# Could questions we have already voted to delete be greyed out as well?

Tags: feature-request, deletion, 10k-tools

I have already voted to delete [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905653/how-to-find-large-int-1-infty-frac1-x-ln-xx-left1x2-right-ln2-x) and it is 'highlighted' on the list of questions with delete votes as shown.

[image]

For the sake of our convenience, could questions we have already voted to delete be greyed out as well, so that we don't need to click on the link and learn that we have done so weeks before?

**I have now asked this on the main [meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316058/could-questions-we-have-already-voted-to-delete-be-greyed-out-as-well).**

Comment: TheSimpliFire.  I agree with this request.  It is absolutely nerve wracking to click on questions or answers in the "Posts with Deletion votes", only to find one has already voted to delete said post.  Wastes what could be more productive time of users' contributions moderating the site.  While, in one sense, as in Community moderation by regular users, the moderation tag is fitting, but when I read the tag description, it seems to be addressing diamond moderators and their moderation.

Comment: I don't know... when I vote something, it just moves to the "recently deleted" list... I think I will close this as [meta-tag:status-norepro]. :D